# What namespace should I use for searching this XML document?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to find the node "PermissionSet" in the following XML.  I'm not very familiar with XPath so i'm trying to walk the tree to get to the node I want.

I load the XML like this:

```
var reader = new XmlTextReader(manifestFilename)
XNamespace _manifestNamespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1";
_appManifest = XElement.Load(reader);
var node1 = _appManifest.Elements(_manifestNamespace + "trustInfo").FirstOrDefault();
var node2 = node1.Elements(_manifestNamespace + "security").FirstOrDefault();
var node3 = node2.Elements(_manifestNamespace + "applicationRequestMinimum").FirstOrDefault();
var node4 = node3.Elements(_manifestNamespace + "PermissionSet").FirstOrDefault();
```

My first node keeps coming up null.  I suspect the namespace i'm using is wrong, but I don't know what to use.  Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
        <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<PermissionSet>` element that you're trying to select resides in this namespace : "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2". That's inherited from it's ancestor `<trustInfo>` element :

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    ........
        <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
    ........
</trustInfo>
```

So you can do this way to get `<PermissionSet>` element :

```
XNamespace v2 = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2";
var result = _appManifest.Root
                         .Element(v2 + "trustInfo")
                         .Element(v2 + "security")
                         .Element(v2 + "applicationRequestMinimum")
                         .Element(v2 + "PermissionSet");
```

**UPDATE :**

Your comment is right, if any element missing (except the last element, PermissionSet), my code will throw null reference exception. But that wasn't the point of this answer, that was only for the sake of simplicity. Anyway, cleaner way to avoid such exception IMHO, is using XPath query :

```
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsManager.AddNamespace("v2", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2");
var result = _appManifest
                .Root
                .XPathSelectElement(
                    "./v2:trustInfo/v2:security/v2:applicationRequestMinimum/v2:PermissionSet"
                    , nsManager);
```

`XPathSelectElement()` is more robust to handle XML with uncontrolled structure. It doesn't throw exception whatever element/attribute missing. It *calmly* returns `null` instead, if no element match the XPath parameter.

Comment: Thanks - this worked.  However, doesn't the sample code you have assume all nodes exist?  What if Security is not there?  Would your sample blow up or is that case handled in the ".Element" implementation?

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but _appManifest doesn't have a .Root property.  It's defined as an XElement.  Where is yours coming from?

Comment: I tried using `XDocument` instead of `XElement`. That's why `_appManifest` has `Root` property in my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
```

The `xmlns=` attribute declares a default namespace, which applies to all non-prefixed elements starting at the element it appears on and "inherited" down to all its descendents until and unless another `xmlns=` attribute appears to set a different default (or to set the default to no-namespace, if the value is `""`).

Note that the default namespace only applies to elements. Attributes are never namespaced unless their Qualified Name includes a namespace prefix.

Comment: I see what you meant, but the element I want is not within the v3 namespace.  It's outside in the v2 area.